# The underlying provider failed on ConnectionString PostgreSql EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql

My web.config:

```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Devart.Data.PostgreSql" /> 
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Devart.Data.PostgreSql" description="Data  Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>

    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="OcrCliaCargoEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/OcrClia.Cargo.OcrCliaCargoDB.csdl|res://*/OcrClia.Cargo.OcrCliaCargoDB.ssdl|res://*/OcrClia.Cargo.OcrCliaCargoDB.msl;provider=Devart.Data.PostgreSql;provider connection string=user id=postgres;host=10.40.51.202;database=cargo;initial schema=tobackup" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>


    <entityFramework>
    <providers>      
      <provider invariantName="Devart.Data.PostgreSql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql.EntityFramework" />
    </providers>    
  </entityFramework>
```

The following error occurs at query time:
Keyword not supported: 'host'

References:

```
<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.0" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Npgsql" version="2.1.3" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Npgsql.EntityFramework" version="2.1.3" targetFramework="net40" />
```

The trial version was installed on my work machine: dcpostgresql.exe

Someone has gone through this problem?

Answer (score 0):

[According to connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/npgsql/), the correct connection parameter for host using npgsql is `Server` not `Host`. That mimics SQL Server's connection string format which uses `Server` as well.

So your connection string should be:

```
<add name="OcrCliaCargoEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/OcrClia.Cargo.OcrCliaCargoDB.csdl|res://*/OcrClia.Cargo.OcrCliaCargoDB.ssdl|res://*/OcrClia.Cargo.OcrCliaCargoDB.msl;provider=Devart.Data.PostgreSql;provider connection string=user id=postgres;Server=10.40.51.202;database=cargo;initial schema=tobackup" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
/// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^
```

Comment: But this same connectionString was created by the tool in the model first.

Comment: Changed as reported, but now returns the error: Keyword not supported: 'server'